# How to increase heap size in Eclipse IDE to run JavaWebApplication?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, heap-memory

How to Increase Tomcat HeapSize (JVM Heap)?
 Getting below error on server console

```
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 01, 2014 8:41:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted               ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]    in state [STARTING_PREP]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1234)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1234)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:822)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:695)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
```

**Will any one help me to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in several ways.
From eclipse you can set in launch configuration arguments. All is described on this [link](http://crunchify.com/how-to-increase-tomcat-heapsize-jvm-heap-in-eclipse-ede/).

Another way is to set CATALINA_OPTS like in your catalina.sh file:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"
```

Another way is to set JAVA_OPTS like this:

`export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx512m"` (but it is not recomended by tomcat).

Try these options and take what are solving your problem.

I hope that helps.